# Azure App Service / Web App instance response time monitoring / alerting

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-log-analytics, azure-appservice, azure-webapps

We have an issue with App Service instances that are getting lazy and getting awful response time. This impacts overall performance and user experience. With Azure App Service Metric, we are able to detect the guilty instance and restart it with the advance reboot feature from diagnostics.

In Azure App Service Metric, we can split the response time (and any other Metric as well) into instances. But how can we create threshold monitoring for instance?
There is a feature to get threshold monitoring on a single defined instance name. But as we do scale a lot, this is not helpful. We forward metrics to a log analytics workspace, but the metrics only contain the overall / average values of all instances and cannot be pinpointed.

Any idea how to implement a response-time threshold monitoring for app service instances?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [auto heal](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2018/09/10/Announcing-the-New-Auto-Healing-Experience-in-App-Service-Diagnostics.html) to automatically recycle the slow instances (also [works for Linux](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2021/04/21/Announcing-Autoheal-for-Azure-App-Service-Linux.html)).

If you only want alerts, you can use custom log queries as a base. You won't be able to get an alert saying "instance XXX is slow", but you can easily achieve an alert like "at least one instance is too slow".

```
requests
| summarize avg(duration) by cloud_RoleInstance, bin(timestamp, 15m)
| render timechart
```

[image]